# Colpitts VCO design problem

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, vco

[image: the final design]

I have found a design to Colpitts VCO to get a sinusoidal output start with 900 MHz - 1100 MHz
but it doesn't work.
this is the link below for the project that I have simulate it, but I can't get sinusoidal signal at the output even when I apply a different voltage from (V2), then I have changed some value and still have the same problem.
My question now is there any problem with the design
and what is it?
[The project link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301868885_Design_of_800_MHz_to_15_GHz_Voltage_Controlled_Oscillator_for_Data_Communication)

Comment: Did you simulate it? What does "doesn't work" actually mean?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with what "doesn't work" means.  I.e. -- tell us what you're seeing, what you want, and if it's not obvious, what the difference is that's bothering you.

Comment: And if by "found a design" you mean you found it on a web page or in a book, please include a citation or link.  Right off I can tell you that the low low value of C1 seems to embody a pretty optimistic expectation for the gain of Q1, and if you look at the impedance of L1 at 1GHz it's practically a short circuit compared to R3.

Comment: thank you all I'm going to add some links for the design .

Comment: When a circuit (intended for oscillation) does not start oscillations, at first, I check the correctness of the circuit and, secondly, the bias point of the active device . As the last step, I control the fulfillment of the oscillation condition. That means: Loop gain analysis (magnitude and phase).